# Spring + hibernate Pb in loading object with a collection from DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

i have two classes A an B like this

```
@Entity
@Table
public class A implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long                idA;
@Column
private String              nomA;
@OneToMany ( mappedBy = "a" )
private Collection < B >    liste;
..........
}


@Entity
@Table
public class B implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long    idB;
@Column
private String  nomB;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn ( name = "idA" )
private A       a;
...........
}
```

this is the A dao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class AdaoImpl implements Adao {

@PersistenceContext ( type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED )
private EntityManager   em;

@Override
public Long addA ( A a ) {

    em.persist ( a );
    return a.getIdA ( );
}

@Override
public A getA ( Long idA ) {

    return em.find ( A.class , idA );
}

}
```

and this the B dao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class BdaoImpl implements Bdao {

@PersistenceContext ( type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED )
private EntityManager   em;

@Override
public Long addB ( B b ) {

    em.persist ( b );
    return b.getIdB ( );
}

@Override
public B getB ( Long idB ) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return em.find ( B.class , idB );
}

}
```

now the A sevice

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AserviceImpl implements Aservice {

@Autowired
private Adao    dao;

@Override
public Long ajouterA ( A a ) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dao.addA ( a );
}

@Override
public A retournerA ( Long idA ) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dao.getA ( idA );
}
.......
}
```

the B service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BserviceImpl implements Bservice {

@Autowired
private Bdao    dao;

@Override
public Long ajouterB ( B b ) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dao.addB ( b );
}

@Override
public B retournerB ( Long idb ) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dao.getB ( idb );
}
....
}
```

when i test it with this code :

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext (
                "spring.xml" );
Aservice aservice = ( Aservice ) ctx.getBean ( "aserviceImpl" );

Bservice bservice = ( Bservice ) ctx.getBean ( "bserviceImpl" );

        A a = new A ( "obj A1" );

        B b1 = new B ( "obj B1" );
        b1.setA ( a );
        B b2 = new B ( "obj B2" );
        b2.setA ( a );
        Long Id = aservice.ajouterA ( a );
        bservice.ajouterB ( b1 );
        bservice.ajouterB ( b2 );

        System.out.println ( ">>>>>>>> "
                + aservice.retournerA ( Id ).toString ( ) );
```

i got >>>>>>>> A [idA=1, nomA=obj A1, liste=null]

I'm wondering why my list is empty

Comment: Try `@OneToMany ( mappedBy = "a", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: still the same result

Answer (score 0):

You have to add B items to collection in A class before saving a

```
a.getListe().add(b1);
a.getListe().add(b2);
```

then call

```
Long Id = aservice.ajouterA ( a );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is hibernates first level cache aka session cache. It caches all entities which were attached to a session only for the lifetime of this session.

So if you call

```
em.find ( A.class , idA );
```

then hibernate will return the cached A, which has no B's assigned to it.

Now you have two options:

1. Use

   ```
   em.refresh(a);
   ```

   That way hibernate reloads a from the database. But for this you also need to declare fetchType.EAGER on the relation to B as @HarshPoddar already pointed out.
2. Add all B's to a

   ```
   a.getListe().add(b1);
   a.getListe().add(b2);
   ```

   as already @laugther posted.

I would go with 2. option.